# Angular2 ngif only show active status data

Tags: angular

I only want to show active outlet. But with this code I able hide the inactive outlet but html element still exist and its break the design. I've shared the output as well. Here is my code:

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-5" *ngFor="let outlet of outletLists">
            <ng-template [ngIf]="outlet.outlet.status === 'active'">

            <div class="card card-xs">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <p class="card-title">{{ outlet.outlet.outletName }} {{ outlet.outlet.status }}</p>
                            <p class="small text-muted">{{ outlet.outlet.location }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </ng-template>
        </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
this.http.get(this.api)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.outletLists = data;
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

**data.json**

```
[{
  "mdrPercent": 21, 
  "index": 0, 
  "transaction": {
     "status": "void", 
     "referenceId": "599515bc8a7b11232747bd95", 
     "customerName": "Darla Madden", 
     "cashier": "Melissa Blackwell", 
     "notes": "anim pariatur duis reprehenderit pariatur duis proident sunt dolore exercitation", 
     "outletName": "Rita Ellis", 
     "deviceId": "599515bc3bc0a8e9aa11f94f", 
     "time": "11:43:44", 
     "date": "2017-02-14", 
     "transactionId": "599515bc74bf959a928ba6dc", 
     "amountPaid": 90.010000000000005
  }, 
  "mdrRebate": 334.88999999999999, 
  "nettAmount": 322.76999999999998, 
  "status": "void", 
  "deviceId": "599515bc58e46cca66c914be", 
  "mdrAmount": 356.44, 
  "time": "10:21:45", 
  "date": "2016-03-07", 
  "transactionId": "599515bc861d4362aadf7fd9", 
  "amountPaid": 90.019999999999996, 
  "transactionAmount": "1,938.75", 
  "isActive": false, 
  "outlet": {
     "status": "active", 
     "outletName": "Olivia Griffin Sdn Bhd", 
     "image": "http://placehold.it/100x100", 
     "outletId": "599515bcb5ed64a61c137bbb", 
     "location": "Goodwin, Malaysia"
  }
```

}]

**output:**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-container` instead of `ng-template`? Also, it's `*ngIf`, not `[ngIf]`?

Comment: Your error is in `*ngFor` because you iterate it in div-tag with col-md-6 css-class. You iteration will create this div for every elemnt in outletLists and after iteration you create ng-template. Try to use ng-container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your template to the following using `ng-container`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let outlet of outletLists">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-5" *ngIf="outlet.outlet.status === 'active'">
        <div class="card card-xs">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <p class="card-title">{{ outlet.outlet.outletName }} {{ outlet.outlet.status }}</p>
                        <p class="small text-muted">{{ outlet.outlet.location }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @SamuelKavinLoganathan No problem, glad it solved your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to see blank container occupying space because your outer `div` already reserved a space without checking `status` of an outlet as it has `div` with `col-md-5` class applied to it.

Change your outer `ngFor` div to use `ng-template` instead of `div` and give apply your alignment classes from inner `ng-if` div(change it from `ng-template`) would solve your issue.

ngIf should be used as `*ngIf`(all structural directive needs start before using them)

```
<ng-template ngFor let-outlet [ngForOf]="outletLists">
    <div class="col-md-6 mb-5" *ngIf="outlet.outlet.status === 'active'">
        <div class="card card-xs">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <p class="card-title">
                           {{ outlet.outlet.outletName }} {{ outlet.outlet.status }}
                        </p>
                        <p class="small text-muted">
                           {{ outlet.outlet.location }}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

[**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/pRFl7GV1rMi0iwbzw38r?p=preview)

Comment: @Arg0n no it should be `*ngIf` only, as it is structural directive

Comment: @Arg0n sorry thats my bad. As I suggested in my answer theoretical way, I forget to remove it from `ngFor` template. thanks for heads up :)

Comment: @Arg0n Silly me, freak, I messed up everything :( though I fixed it now, thanks for pointing it out. I don't know how did I missing so many things..

Comment: It happens, our answers are pretty much the same now though. :)

Comment: @Arg0n that's why upvoted yours, thanks for correcting me as well :)

Comment: Now, I got this this error
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'.

Comment: @SamuelKavinLoganathan this is wiered, which angular version you are using? Please check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pRFl7GV1rMi0iwbzw38r?p=preview)

Comment: @PankajParkar Im using angular 4.0.0. Yes i did same thing as in plunke. I got error if used ngForOf. Now working fine. Thanks your time :)

Comment: @SamuelKavinLoganathan then just curious, what was missing stuff?

Comment: @PankajParkar ngForOf doesn't work for me but in plunker is without  ngForOf works fine. Thank you for explanation. Now I understand better :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, there is a column created for each outlet in the outer most div, no matter if the div has no content it. An easy solution might be this:

```
<div *ngFor="let outlet of outletLists">
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-5" *ngIf="outlet.outlet.status === 'active'">
    <div class="card card-xs">
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-body">
            <p class="card-title">{{ outlet.outlet.outletName }} {{ outlet.outlet.status }}</p>
            <p class="small text-muted">{{ outlet.outlet.location }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So now it doesn't create a column until the if condition is fulfilled.

Comment: ngFor & ngIf directive can't be used together.. though `[ngIf]` should be `*ngIf`

Comment: I copied his code, and yes that was my bad.. Didn't get to test it

Comment: @lexith yes, I meant to say same thing, they can't be used together on same element. I wrote a comment based on initial answerer, seems like answer edited this..